# Getting 66: insufficient priority. when trying to push transaction

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoinjs-lib

Basically I getting `66: insufficient priority. Code:-26` when I trying to push transaction

I already tried to increase fees manually.
`AMOUNT_TOSEND` is in satoshis

1. I take `total_received` value from `https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/addrs/` + address + '/full?limit=50'
   and multiply it by `100000000`
2. I take fee from here: https://test-insight.bitpay.com/api/utils/estimatefee
   and multiply it by `100000000`
3. Here is how I calculate outputs:
   tx.addOutput(ADDRESS_BENEFICIARY, Number(AMOUNT_TOSEND))
   tx.addOutput(ADDRESS_BENEFICIARY, Number(balance) - (Number(AMOUNT_TOSEND) + Number(fee)))
4. Pasting on https://test-insight.bitpay.com/tx/send and getting `66: insufficient priority. Code:-26`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix after I started to use transaction amount instead of the total balance, also multiply fee by transaction size in bytes, but not sure I exactly need it

Comment: Works without multiplying fee by number of bytes